# CSS float property to align div's

Tags: html, css

I'm having some serious trouble getting things to float left correctly, or rather getting elements to float "true" left.

This is my current output:

[image: current (broken) output]

and this is what I am hoping to achieve:

[image: ideal output]

here is a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fWK2A/), any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

**html:**

```
            <div id="content">

                <div class="box1">
                    1
                </div>
                <div class="box2">
                    2
                </div>
                <div class="box1">
                    3
                </div>
                <div class="box1">
                    4
                </div>
                <div class="box1">
                    5
                </div>

            </div>
```

**css:**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#content {
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    width:180px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.box1 {
    margin: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

.box2 {
    margin: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 110px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Oh and just a little note, I'd prefer to accomplish this without using javascript but am happy to use it as a last resort.

Comment: Please use summat like jsfiddle.net

Comment: You won't accomplish that with floats. You'll probably want to look at a grid system from Bootstrap or another provider.

Comment: or a (please don't throw stones) a table?

Comment: @EdHeal I have a jsfiddle link in there.

Comment: [A complete guide to **Flexbox**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I rearranged the divs a little bit, made some new block formatting contexts and got this: http://jsfiddle.net/fWK2A/1/

Comment: @biziclop that works for this specific example, but the thing I'm using this for is going to potentially use hundreds of these boxes in random orders. Thank you though.

Comment: If you change order of the divs in the markup to `1,4,2,3,5`, then you can use floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can't be done with only css at the moment, maybe in some short future, but there is a lot of javascript solutions to this and making some research i found [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html), wich i think is the most popular. You should try it.

Answer (score 3):

Floats are not capable of the layout you are looking for. You need something more the columns.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts

But you have to be careful of the cross browser and they are not great at percentage widths either (from experience).

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I'm going to use a jQuery plugin called [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) seems to do what floats cannot.

Again though, many thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunately, multi-column layout doesn't work either, see http://jsfiddle.net/fWK2A/5/

Answer (score 2):

I got something similar to what you want

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fWK2A/2/)

```
.box5 {
    margin: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    background-color: red;
    position:absolute;
    float: right;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    float:left;
    left:150px;
    top:80px;
}
```

Comment: That works nicely for the layout I used as the example, and I thank you for that. However the reason I am asking this question is because I want to be able to create many different kinds of boxes and populate the page with them (potentially hundreds of them) according to a random numerical value.

Ideally they would also shift around as the page is resized.

Comment: @CameronGuthrie if you find this answer correct then please mark it answered. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i have found answer to what you are looking for.... just see this fiddle i have edited...

```
.box4 {
margin: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
background-color: red;
position: relative;
float:left;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
margin-top:-50px;
margin-left:3px;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/fWK2A/6/embedded/result/