# Divide vertical columns and align them

Tags: html, css

I'am trying to create a layout similar to the one below:

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|      |                     |      |
|      |                     |      |
|      |                     |      |
|  1   |                     |   2  |
|      |                     |      |
|_ _ _ |          5          |_ _ _ |
|      |                     |      |
|      |                     |      |
|   3  |                     |   4  |
|      |                     |      |
|      |                     |      |
|_ _ _ |_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _|_ _ _ |
```

I'am having trouble in two things:

1. Dividing vertical columns;
2. Align 1 and 2 with 5;

[The website with the example/code](http://html5testing.eu5.org/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS float property to align div's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124025/css-float-property-to-align-divs)

Comment: Please clarify "Align 1 and 2 with 5" and post your relevant HTML/CSS in the post since most of us don't like to dig into a website's source code and follow links to HTML files and build a jsfiddle and so on....

Comment: Did the search, didn't find that question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#content {
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    width:180px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vishalkin/fWK2A/7/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use % to mention widths of vertical columns.
You can use below structure,

```
<div>
    <div class="leftside">
        <div class="1"></div>
        <div class="3"></div>
    <div>

    <div class="Center">
        <div class="5"></div>
    <div>
    <div class="rightside">
        <div class="2"></div>
        <div class="4"></div>
    <div>
</div>

<style>
.leftside
{
    float:left;
    width:15%;
}

.rightside
{
    float:right;
    width:15%;
}
.center
{
    floas:left;
    width:70%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
<div style="width:100%">
<div style="width:15%; float:left">
    <div style="width:100%"></div>
    <div style="width:100%"></div>
</div>
<div style="width:70%; float:left">
</div>
<div>
    <div style="width:100%"></div>
    <div style="width:100%"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Set height as you desired.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code

```
<table border="1">
     <tr><td >1</td><td rowspan="2" colspan="2" width="70%" align= "center" >5</td ><td >2</td></tr>
     <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
     </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this CSS layout:
[The Square Grid](http://thesquaregrid.com/)

That's an awesome layout that can solve all of your problems.